# Problem with adding constraint that wont let me insert members with certain columns

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

I have created this table

```
CREATE TABLE members
(
    member_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    last_name VARCHAR(20),
    web_page VARCHAR(200),
    e_mail VARCHAR(200),
    cv VARCHAR(800),
    dep_id INT,
    teacher_id INT,
    CHECK (dep_id  IN (1, 2, 3) AND teacher_id IS NULL)
);
```

I want to add a constraint that when you insert a member with a dep_id of 1, 2 or 3 then u must be required to pick a teacher_id of NULL.

When I use this table, it won't let me insert a member with dep_id of 4 and whatever teacher_id tho.

I tried to do the check on the same line as dep_id but it wont pass cause its
about another column too(teacher_id).(someone can even think of a trigger but i don't think its necessary here)

I use SQL Server

Comment: You've asked this question Dec 23 - and you **got** a valid, proper answer - why ask again? Have you tried Gordon's suggestion of using a check **constraint**? Anything wrong with that?

Comment: You got the constraint **wrong**- Gordon's correct answer was: `check (dep_id not in (1, 2, 3) or teacher_id is not null);`

Comment: @marc_s actually when i use this it doesnt let me insert a member at all

Comment: Can't reproduce - with Gordon's constraint, insert works just fine - for `dep_id` in 1,2,3, you **must** provide a valid `teacher_id` - if the `dep_id` is anything else, the `teacher_id` isn't required (can be `NULL`) - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48667/3

Comment: dude i made it work i realised that i had mispronounced my previous question so i should have make it check (dep_id not in (1, 2, 3) or teacher_id is null);

Comment: thanks for ur answers tho much appreciated